# Limit of the integrand of an improper integral.

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, gre-exam

I don't have any idea about how to solve the following GRE question. Could anyone give me some tips how to solve this kind of problems?

Let $f: (1,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a function, such that the improper integral $\int_1^{\infty} f(x) dx$ converges. Which of the following is true:

I) $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists.

II) If $f(x)$ is monotonous decreasing, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists.

III) If $f(x)$ has derivatives of every order then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can find counterexamples to the first and the third cases. The second case is the right one.

Comment: (and you also know what $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ is)

Comment: Take a look to this similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223348/integration-and-limit-of-a-function/223360#223360